# Implementing generic interfaces in Java with common code

Tags: java, generics, reflection, interface

Suppose I have interfaces as follows:

```
public interface UnaryFunction<Ret, Arg> {
    public Ret invoke(Arg arg);
}

public interface BinaryFunction<Ret, Arg1, Arg2> {
    public Ret invoke(Arg1 arg, Arg2 arg);
}
```

Now suppose I have a wrapper class like so:

```
public class ConstructorWrapper<Ret> {
    // Wrapper for a java.lang.reflect.Constructor
    private final Constructor<Ret> constructor;

    // Try blocks in the following elided for brevity

    // Trying to implement UnaryFunction<Ret, Arg> with this
    public <Arg> Ret invoke(Arg arg) { return constructor.newInstance(arg); }

    // Trying to implement BinaryFunction<Ret, Arg1, Arg2> with this
    public <Arg1, Arg2> Ret invoke(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) { return constructor.newInstance(arg1, arg2); }
}
```

How do I change this so that `ConstructorWrapper` is declared to implement both `UnaryFunction` and `BinaryFunction`?  Better yet, how do I make it so that passing in a one-argument constructor results in a `ConstructorWrapper` object (or subclass therein) that only implements `UnaryFunction` and passing in a two-argument constructor results in a `ConstructorWrapper` object that only implements `BinaryFunction` (ie. so you don't pass in a unary constructor in a place where a `BinaryFunction` is expected)?  Preferably with as little repetition as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with:

```
public class ConstructorWrapper<Ret, Arg, Arg1, Arg2>
  implements UnaryFunction<Ret, Arg>, BinaryFunction<Ret, Arg1, Arg2>
```

What is wrong with having a class provide both APIs?

If you don't have both, make that two wrappers. They can have an *abstract superclass* if you want to reduce code duplication. But if you want type safety, the wrapper classes should implement the interfaces!

Comment: Arg, Arg1, and Arg2 are merely type parameters.  They are not concrete types.

Comment: `ConstructorWrapper<Ret>` should be `ConstructorWrapper<Ret, Arg1, Arg2>` other wise there is a compilation issue.

Comment: Of course. Thanks. Note that you can have `Arg` and `Arg1` be the same type, if you want. The point is, I have the impression I don't fully understand the question yet.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I make it so that passing in a one-argument constructor results in a ConstructorWrapper object (or subclass therein) that only implements UnaryFunction and passing in a two-argument constructor results in a ConstructorWrapper object that only implements BinaryFunction.

This would only be possible if you have two different *classes* to create these `ConstructorWrapper` objects, eg

```
class ConstructorWrapperUnary<Ret, Arg1> extends ConstructorWrapper {...}

class ConstructorWrapperBinary<Ret, Arg1, Arg2> extends ConstructorWrapper {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a factory instead:

```
public class ConstructorFactory
{
    public static <Ret, Arg> Ret invoke(UnaryFunction<Ret, Arg> f, Arg arg)
    {
        return f.invoke(arg);
    }

    public static <Ret, Arg1, Arg2> Ret invoke(BinaryFunction<Ret, Arg1, Arg2> f, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2)
    {
        return f.invoke(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```